# Examples of RKHS that are "classical"

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Among the so-called "classical" Hilbert spaces ($L^2$, Sobolev, Hardy, Bergman, etc.), which are very well-studied, which are RKHSs?

It is easy to construct example of RKHSs by applying the Moore–Aronszajn theorem and defining appropriate kernels, but I would like to firm up my intuition about these spaces by comparing them to "what I know". Surprisingly, I have not found much about this in the literature, although I am certain I am just looking in the wrong places.

Comment: Honestly pretty much any Hilbert space of functions you'll come across is a RKHS (Lest we forget, $L^2$ spaces are not actually spaces of functions).

Comment: Morrey's inequality tells you which Sobolev spaces embed into the space of continuous functions, and thus are RKHSs.  $L^2(X,\mu)$ is an RKHS if and only if $(X,\mu)$ is purely atomic.

Comment: For the uninitiated, presumably RKHS stands for [Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space)?

Comment: A non-rigorous POV that I think is still useful: if you have some space of functions on a set $X$, how do you know if it is complete w.r.t. a given inner product? You'll need to show that given a Cauchy sequence $(f_n)$ there is some **genuine function** $f$ on $X$ that is the norm limit of the $f_n$, and in many cases the only way to define $f(x)$ is to know that the sequence $f_n(x)$ is Cauchy. But how do you get pointwise Cauchy estimates from a Cauchy norm condition? Well, you probably want "evaluation at x" to be continuous w.r.t. your norm -- and that is the RKHS condition.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is: if your original inner product space of functions is indeed a Hilbert space, the chances are that this can only be proved when point evaluations are continuous, i.e. if you have a RKHS. Now as I said above this is not a proof, but it's an attempt to give some justfiication for @YonahBorns-Weil's comment (which I tend to agree with).

Comment: @YemonChoi + YonahBorns-Weil: Thank you for the suggestions! I guess what I was looking for is a rigorous statement of these claims. In fact, I finally found some details here: https://www.math.uh.edu/~vern/rkhs.pdf If either of you would like to your own details as an answer, I will happily accept it. Otherwise, I might self-answer with this link.